# Select statement for locked files

Tags: oracle, logging, locking, external

I'm looking for select statement displaying locked files by oracle.exe, such as log and bad files related to external tables.

Comment: What do you mean by "locked files"? You can't do much to the external file system from within the database.

Comment: I am pretty sure the database does not track this level of information about the state of operating system logfiles.

Comment: I'm talking about the files which are generated when oracle is reading file for external table. Such as log, bad and dis files. Looks like one of my log files remains locked after reading, no matter I'm using the exact same external table config for other tables.